# How to pass the calculated amount to paypal

Tags: php, paypal, currency, paypal-sandbox

I have created  price calculation using java script.

when user entered a value it automatically calculates the price total and displays.i want to pass the calculated value to the PayPal(i m using buy now button).

How i pass the value to PayPal sandbox ? is this possible

this is my java script calculation

```
          <script type="text/javascript">

   function  doMath() { 

                     var nvalue; var amount;
                    var price=0.10;
                    nvalue = parseInt(document.getElementById("message").value);
                     amount=(nvalue*price);
                       document.getElementById("total").value=amount ;
                    }
</script>
```

This is my Html

```
         <input type="" name="message" id="message" onkeyup="doMath()" maxlength="60">message 
          <input type="text" name="total" id="total" maxlength="60">amount
```

This Paypal button link

```
         <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0"  name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
```

i want to pass the calculated amount in the Paypal button link is this possible? i m new to paypal.

Comment: Is this possible .please anyone help me out on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the PayPal button is submitting the same form as the `total` text field is located in, then you need to change the name of that `total` field to;

```
 <input type="text" name="amount" id="total" maxlength="60">
```

This will submit the amount to PayPal.